# use org.eclipse.core.resources method in my java app

Tags: java, eclipse

I have a java application in eclipse luna. In my workspace there are a few large projects.
I want to use *org.eclipse.jdt.ui* functions, and first I have to get the workspace with `ResourcesPlugin.getWorkspace()` method.

Apparently as a Java application, I cannot use *ResourcesPlugin* functions. There are a large number of Java class files so I am not able to import into the eclipse workspace as a project.

So, my question is: can I use methods from *org.eclipse.jdt.ui* and *org.eclipse.core.resources* (programmatically), and if I can, how?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With a few exceptions you can't use any Eclipse plugins in an ordinary Java program. You certainly can't use UI and resources code.

This is because the plugins rely on the Eclipse plugin support code being initialized properly when Eclipse starts.

You can write an Eclipse 'headless' application which lets you run without the GUI.